# Spark JDBC filter records outside of boundaries

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm trying to optimize a daily job that pulls three months of data from a MySQL table into parquet on HDFS. They're currently using `mysqldump` in a very creative way but have a spark/hdfs ecosystem so I thought I'd use that instead.

**BACKGROUND**

I defined how to read the database like this:

```
# time_col column is epoch as an integer
# start_time is beginning of three month period
# end_time is end of three month period

df = session.read \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("driver", driver) \
  .option("dbtable", "table1") \
  .option("user", username) \
  .option("password", password) \
  .option("partitionColumn","time_col") \
  .option("upperBound", end_time) \
  .option("lowerBound", start_time) \
  .option("numPartitions", partitions) \
  .load()
```

This works really really well except for the first and last partitions that have 10's of billions of records that I don't even want;

In order to filter out the vast majority of the table, I updated `dtable` like so

```
.option("dtable", "(select * from table1 WHERE time_col >= {} and time_col < {}) as table2".format(start_time, end_time))
```

This sort of worked. When `end_time` - `start_time` is small the job runs very well, but it is not scalable to 3 months.

This is because the query for each partition now includes a derived table

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM (SELECT * From table1 WHERE time_col >=1585780000 AND time_col < 1585866400 ) as table2 WHERE `time_col` >= 1585808800 AND `time_col` < 1585812400;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL     | NULL    | NULL | 25048354 | Using where |
|  2 | DERIVED     | table1     | range | time_col      | time_col | 4       | NULL | 25048354 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

In contrast, here's what the generated query looked like when I was just using `dtable = "table1"`; much simpler and faster

```
explain SELECT * From table1 WHERE `time_col` >= 1585808800 AND `time_col` < 1585812400;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1 | range | time_col      | time_col | 4       | NULL | 1097631 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

**QUESTION**

Is there any way for me to filter out the data outside of `upperBound` and `lowerBound` while still keeping the simpler query? Like either preventing the 1st and last partitions from being ran or by overwriting `dtable` at runtime so it replaces the subquery with just `table1`?

**PARAMETERS**

I only have read access to the table that lives on MySQL 5.7 and can't create views or indices

I'm developing on Spark 3.1, but I believe production is on Spark 2

Yes, I've considered Spark Structured Streaming and other streaming options, but that is not the direction we're going at the moment.

Comment: There is no "MySQL 7.6" check with `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: Consider building and maintaining a "summary table":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: Oh my, very bad typo. Fixed it @RickJames thanks

Comment: @RickJames Thanks, but I have read-only access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I could avoid the subquery if I tacked on a where() method. Example:

```
# time_col column is epoch as an integer
# start_time is beginning of three month period
# end_time is end of three month period

df = session.read \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("driver", driver) \
  .option("dbtable", "table1") \
  .option("user", username) \
  .option("password", password) \
  .option("partitionColumn","time_col") \
  .option("upperBound", end_time) \
  .option("lowerBound", start_time) \
  .option("numPartitions", partitions) \
  .load()

# This filters out everything outside of boundaries
# without creating a subquery
df.where('time_col >= {} AND time_col < {}'.format(start_time,end_time))
```

Spark was able to just tack on the clauses along with the clauses created by the partitioning logic. Hence, no subquery and better performance.